# How to rotate text in a cell and center it vertically and horizontally?

Tags: tables, rotating

I am creating a table and, after using `\multirow`, I want to rotate the text of this column and have it centered vertically and horizontally inside its cell. The code I am using would be similar to this one:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
\multirow{8}{*}{Text} & row 1 & row 1 \\
 & row 2 & row 2 \\
 & row 3 & row 3 \\
 & row 4 & row 4 \\
 & row 5 & row 5 \\
 & row 6 & row 6 \\
 & row 7 & row 7 \\
 & row 8 & row 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think, you are after `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The code is there. Could you please elaborete?

Comment: It's a fragment, not a MWE ;-)

Comment: A MWE contains ideally a code that runs: I can't feed a `\begin{tabular}` stuff to LaTeX without document around it. So it's a fragment of something that could work ;-)

Answer (score 27):

You can do this with or without [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow). Use [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) for the rotation via `\rotatebox[<opts>]{<deg>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
  \hline
  \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} & row 1 & row 1 \\
   & row 2 & row 2 \\
   & row 3 & row 3 \\
   & row 4 & row 4 \\
   & row 5 & row 5 \\
   & row 6 & row 6 \\
   & row 7 & row 7 \\
   & row 8 & row 8 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
  \hline
   & row 1 & row 1 \\
   & row 2 & row 2 \\
   & row 3 & row 3 \\
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} & row 4 & row 4 \\
   & row 5 & row 5 \\
   & row 6 & row 6 \\
   & row 7 & row 7 \\
   & row 8 & row 8 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With `multirow` you don't need to worry about the placement, while without you need to place the text in the appropriate location, and perhaps lower/raise it into position. Also, you have to flatten the content (done by using the `[0pt][0pt]` options to `\raisebox`) so it doesn't impede in the row height - something that is naturally done by `multirow`.

There might be a slight discrepancy between the two methods, but it is negligible.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Christian Hupfer, you can do that with `rotatebox`.  But maybe, depending on the real contents, aesthetically, you'll prefer the vertical text ‘rule-free’. Some adjusment is often necessary to ensure vertical centring:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
\multirow{8}{*}[-0.4ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Some text}} & row 1 & row 1 \\
 & row 2 & row 2 \\
 & row 3 & row 3 \\
 & row 4 & row 4 \\
 & row 5 & row 5 \\
 & row 6 & row 6 \\
 & row 7 & row 7 \\
 & row 8 & row 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hskip 1 cm
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c| }
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{8}{*}[-0.4ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Some text}} & row 1 & row 1 \\
 & row 2 & row 2 \\
 & row 3 & row 3 \\
 & row 4 & row 4 \\
 & row 5 & row 5 \\
 & row 6 & row 6 \\
 & row 7 & row 7 \\
 & row 8 & row 8 \\
 \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you reduce the spacing on top of and below "Some Text". I tried doing it with a block of text that is on two lines and adjusting the column width causes strange things to happen.

Comment: @Veridian: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean with ‘reducing’ – for me, there's nothing to reduce since there are  8 rows. Could give some more details?

Comment: @Veridian: Maybe you mean the space which is physically on the left and on the right?

Comment: Yeah, I want the column width to be reduced, but just the first column.

Comment: Because you have rotated text on two lines?

Comment: Yes using this command: \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\pbox{3cm}{\relax\ifvmode\centering\fi THIS\\THISTHIS THISES}} and not sure how to reduce spacing on left side of rotated box

Comment: Try this: `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\pbox{4cm}{\relax\ifvmode\centering\linespread{0.65}\fi THIS\\THISTHIS THISES}`. Also you can locally reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, using this preamble for the table: `\begin{tabular}{ |@{\,\,}c@{}|c|c| }`.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Block{8-1}{\rotate Text} & row 1 & row 1 \\
 & row 2 & row 2 \\
 & row 3 & row 3 \\
 & row 4 & row 4 \\
 & row 5 & row 5 \\
 & row 6 & row 6 \\
 & row 7 & row 7 \\
 & row 8 & row 8 \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]