# How to vertically align rotated text and images in a tabular?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, rotating

Consider following MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Hello} & d \\ \hline
e & f \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{There} & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{dummy.png} \\ \hline
e & f \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- In the second line of the first table, the rotated text ("Hello") is vertically aligned with the text ("d") of its adjacent cell.
- In the second table, there is a problem with the vertical alignment : the text seems to be aligned at the bottom [or left before rotation], and there is a whitespace below the figure. How can one obtain vertical alignment in this case?

I found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201696/how-to-rotate-text-in-a-cell-and-center-it-vertically-and-horizontally) but it seems my problem is caused by the fact of adding an image in the adjacent cell.

Comment: to see why you get the layout you show draw in the baseline for the second table row, it passes through the centre of `There`  (as you used origin=c) and along the bottom of the image, so space has to be added under the image to allow both to sit on the baseline.

Comment: It should be noted that in many cases the baseline is slightly below the center.  One can ishow the location of the baseline using `\llap{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}` AFTER the text.

Answer (score 2):

For the second table with image:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{There} 
         & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c,
                            margin= 0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{example-image-duck} \\
         \hline
e       & f \\ 
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to choose the margins? Do they depend on the chosen height of the image?

Comment: @Karlo, margin size is determined absolutely, it is independent from image size. it is defined as `margin= <left> <above> <below> <right>`.sinceon the left and tight  size of image are already space `\tabcolspace` (6pt), You only need add space above and below of image. If you like to have the same space above/below as is left/right, than `margin= 0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt`. For details see documentation for `adjustbox` package.