# Rotated text in table cell refused to center, and ignores line break

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, multirow, rotating

This is my first question on this site, and I'm also still a newbie with LaTeX and its plethora of packages.

I'm trying to recreate this table: [image]

I found [this old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201696/how-to-rotate-text-in-a-cell-and-center-it-vertically-and-horizontally) and tried to recreate it with the `\rotatebox` method, but the result **ignores the forced line break in the first column, and also ignores the centering of the second column.**
Here's the code I used (I'm working in Overleaf if that's important):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Confusion matrix and performance metrics calculated from the combinations of true and predicted conditions}\label{tab:tableConfMatrix2}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Prediction/ classification}} & \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & positive & negative & \\
    \hline
    \multirow[c]{2}{=}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{True condition /\newline gold standard}}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{positive} & True positive, TP & False negative, FN & Sensitivity\newline= TP / (TP + FN)\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{negative} & False positive, FP & True negative, TN & Specificity\newline= TN / (TN + FP)\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Positive predictive value\newline= TP / (TP + FP) & Negative predictive value\newline= TN / (TN + FN) & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried the `\begin{sideways}` command from the `rotating` package with exactly the same result. Now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is your problem solved in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40465/line-break-in-rotatebox-in-table)?

Answer (score 1):

My answer based on [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), which i would suggest if you have to deal with that kind of tables. I am not entirely happy with this because I've had to do a little tuning

[image]

In general, `tabularray` has more intuitive interface and its functionality can be extended by a number of libraries; some of them provide similar functionality to standalone packages, mainly `booktabs`, `siunitx` etc.

I also set custom background at 4 corners. If you don't like it, just remove `bg=cellbg` from affected cells as well as the line `\colorlet{cellbg}{black!10}` and the macro `\uspackage{xcolor}` from the preamble.

Other points.
A few extra macros and custom lengths are added to slightly clarify the main code and avoid repetition.

---

EDIT. While the right-hand side lower corner is greyed-out, I believe there is one more metric

```
Accuracy = (TP + TN)/N
```

I could change the code to include it in the table or you may want to try it yourself. Let me know if you have a problem with that.

---

The example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\newcommand\Tr[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\colorlet{cellbg}{black!10}
\newlength\heavyline    \setlength{\heavyline}{0.12em}
\newlength\lightline    \setlength{\lightline}{0.08em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\textwidth,
        colspec = {| Q | Q | X[3,c,h] | X[3,c,h] | X[3,c,h] |},
        hline{1,6} = {\heavyline}, hline{3,5} = {\lightline},
        vline{1,6} = {\heavyline}, vline{3,5} = {\lightline},
        cell{1}{1} = {r=2,c=2}{bg=cellbg},
        cell{3}{1} =     {r=2}{cmd=\textbf},
        cell{1}{5} =     {r=2}{bg=cellbg},
        cell{5}{1} =     {c=2}{bg=cellbg},
        cell{5}{5} =          {bg=cellbg},
        cell{3-4}{3-4} = {cmd=\rule{0pt}{18pt},c,h},
        cells = {font=\small},
    }
    && \SetCell[c=2]{cmd=\textbf} Prediction / Classification && \\
    \hline
    && positive & negative & \\
    \rot{\Tr{True condition\\gold standard}} &
    \rot{\Tr{positive} } &
    True positive, TP &
    False negative, FN &
    {Sensitivity\\TP/(TP + FN)} \\ 
    \hline
    &
    \rot{\Tr{negative} } &
    False positive, FP &
    True negative, TN &
    {Specificity\\TN/(TN + FP)} \\
    &&
    {Positive\\Predictive Value\\TP/(TP + FP)} &
    {Negative\\Predictive Value\\TN/(TN + FN)} & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```